# Android: Display Multi Buttons in A RelativeLayout like FourSquare

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, foursquare

I would like to make a tag view like the one below which allows the display of tags with multi-columns (1,2,3 columns depending on the width) and the tag should be clickable for further actions.

I think the traditional gridview is not suitable but i don't know how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This repo may will help you. Your ss match with this repo's gif.
https://github.com/Cutta/TagView

Comment: Hi @Cuneyt:
Thanks for the sharing! The library meets my need and I don't know why people vote it down...

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Fancy buttons.

[image]
[image]

Please have a look of this demo.

https://github.com/medyo/fancybuttons

Really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: why does he need? its an option to use the library there was never a need for using such library.